# Volume under a contour surface in matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, contourf

I am using `contourf` to generate a contour plot for a 2 variable function.

My function is `Z = f(x,y)`.

I generate x and y through `meshgrid` function in matlab and generate values for `Z` and then plot the contour using `contour(x,y,z)`.

I want to be able to calculate the volume under this generated contour. Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Area or volume? The title and question mention the opposite

Comment: Sorry about that. Volume not area. I'll it in the post too

Comment: You can use [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) to integrate `z = @(x,y) f(x,y)` over the region you plotted.

Comment: integral2 should work rite ? I was planning on using trapz to calculate the volume but running it twice along the 2 dimensions.

Comment: Isnt the integral2 function limited to planar surfaces ? My surface is not a plane it is a curved surface.

Comment: No.  `integral2` will integrate any explicit, two-variable function using an adaptive method to ensure accuracy.

Comment: I tried the integral2 function but I ended up getting a negative value for the volume. My function is of the form:

model = @(x,y) (b(1)*(b(3) - ((b(3)-1)*exp(-b(2)*x)))) - (b(4)*y);

xmin = 0;
xmax = 9000;
ymin = 1;
ymax = 90;

tox = integral2(model,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,'Method','iterated');

I ran this on matlab and ended up with a negative value. I can't exactly put my finger on what I am doing wrong. @TroyHaskin could you please help

Comment: You're probably not doing anything wrong. Depending on the values of `b`, your `model` has a long-run behavior (large `x`) of `b(1)*b(3) - b(4)*y` if `b(2)` is positive.  This will lead to negative volumes since `integral2` computes the **signed** volume (analogous to a negative integral in one-dimension; e.g., `int(-x^2,-1,1)`).

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you simply use a **integral approximation** like a riemann sum? Assuming uniform spacing for x and y something like this should work

```
delta_x = x(2) - x(1);
delta_y = y(2) - y(1);
vol = sum(Z(:)) * delta_x * delta_y;
```

This will not be the EXACT volume, but an approximation. Since you know your function you would get a more accurate answer by performing the integration of the function. But if you did not know the function you would use this method or any other **numerical integration** method.

From calculus we know that an actual integral is just a reimann sum where the width of each interval is infinitely small, so this should be a valid approximation

Comment: I am not sure. My surface is curved because the function involves exponential and linear terms which is why I am a little confused

Comment: the function output `z` can be any shape. As long as your x and y have uniform spacing. meaning `x(n) - x(n-1) == x(k) - x(k-1)` for all `n and k` where `n != k and n,k are integers` the same would go for y. Basically this method places a cube of width `delta_x` length `delta_y` and height `z` at every value in z, and adds them all together to produce `vol`

Comment: so your suggestion is find value of the function Z at all n values of x and y. Then proceed to sum everything and multiply it by delta x and delta y correct ? @andrew

Comment: correct @VigneshR it is exactly the same as using a reimann sum for area approximation http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html but now we are doing volume, so instead of each interval being a rectangle of width `delta_x` and height `y` we have cubes as described in my previous comment. An integral is nothing more than a riemann sum where the interval (delta_x and delta_y for a double integral) is infinitely small. This will not be the EXACT volume, but an approximation. You would get a more accurate answer if you actually performed the integration of your function.